# Some help for the CAM (causal additive model) in cdt (causal discovery toolbox) pacakage

Tags: python, r, eclipse-cdt, causality

There is always a bug when I try to launch CAM in cdt.
The code is here.

```
import networkx as nx
from cdt.causality.graph import CAM
from cdt.data import load_dataset
data, graph=load_dataset("sachs")
obj=CAM()
```

The error is   File D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\cdt\causality\graph\CAM.py:124 in **init**
raise ImportError("R Package CAM is not available.")

ImportError: R Package CAM is not available.

Tried to install the CAM package in R and changed the rpath in Setting.py but no use.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was create a small script to download all the R requirements (the R language must already be downloaded therefore).

I believe a `yaml` file is still in the project folder (available [here](https://github.com/FenTechSolutions/CausalDiscoveryToolbox/blob/master/r_requirements.txt)).

Nevertheless, here is what I did:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data

utils = importr('utils')
base = importr('base')

with open('r_requirements.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for pack in text:
    utils.install_packages(pack)
```